# String difference algorithm

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings

I would like to get a feedback about the code below. Is there any way to improve its performance? Maybe you know input values that might print bad output? The idea of the code is to count unique characters from `s2` that are not listed in `s1`.

[Ideone.com URL](http://ideone.com/K3URn6)

```
class Combine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s1 = bi.readLine();
        String s2 = bi.readLine();

        String usedCharacters = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
            String c = Character.toString(s2.charAt(i));
            if(!usedCharacters.contains(c) && !s1.contains(c)) 
                usedCharacters += c;
        }

        System.out.println(usedCharacters.length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to report the characters in any particular order. As a result, there's some tricks we can do to improve the performance.

Other tricks to use are:

- work using primitive `char[]` arrays instead of Strings.
- use better variable names

Sorting the data is a good first step:

```
    char[] expect = bi.readLine().toCharArray();
    char[] search = bi.readLine().toCharArray();
```

Now we sort them both:

```
Arrays.sort(expect);
Arrays.sort(search);
```

Then, we loop through the `search` values, and look for characters that do not appear in `expect`:

```
StringBuilder usedCharacters = new StringBuilder();
int searchPos = 0;
while (searchPos < search.length) {
    int expectPos = Arrays.binarySearch(expect, search[searchPos]);
    if (expectPos < 0) {
        usedCharacters.append(search[searchPos]);
    }
    // advance to the next character, may be duplicates.
    searchPos++;
    while (searchPos < search.length && search[searchPos - 1] == search[searchPos]) {
        searchPos++;
    }
}

return usedCharacters.toString();
```

Now, how will this relate in terms of performance?

Your current code loops through each search character, which is an \$O(n)\$ operation. For each character, it then does a search through previously searched characters, and also the unsearched characters. The combination of these two loops leads to a \$O(nm)\$ operation.

In contrast, the sorts on the input data are \$O(n \log{n})\$, and \$O(m \log{m})\$ and the subsequent searches are \$O(n \log{m})\$

The end result will be much more favourable than \$O(nm)\$

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely take a deeper look into your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from not using a better algorithm, there are two efficiency eaters in your code:

```
String usedCharacters = "";
... in loop
    usedCharacters += c;
```

This copies the whole content and adds a single character.

```
String c = Character.toString(s2.charAt(i));
... ....contains(c)
```

You're converting a `char` into a `String` just to be able to use `contains(String)`. While there's no `contains(char)`, `indexOf(char) > -1` does the job.

---

A simple and efficient solution could go like this:

```
boolean[] seen = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE]; // one slot per char
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i<s1.length; ++i) {
    char c = s1.charAt(i);
    seen[c] = true;
}

for (int i=0; i<s2.length; ++i) {
    char c = s2.charAt(i);
    if (!seen[c]) { 
        result.append(c);
        seen[c] = true;    
    }
}
```

This needs one byte per a possible character (there are \$2^{16}\$ of them), i.e., 64 KiB. If you care, use a `BitSet` instead, which needs a single bit instead of byte and grows as needed (up to 8 KiB if very strange characters occur).

The complexity is `O(s1.length() + s2.length())`, hard to beat given that you must look at each character.

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach 1:

Traverse first string and store the occurrences of the characters present either in a HashMap or Boolean array.

Traverse through the second array S2 and count the unique occurrence of its characters.

#### Approach 2:

You can also use the java TreeSet to get  sorted single occurrences of each string and compare character by character or use `StringUtils.difference` on the sorted character set.

Comment: Could you also explain why your suggestions would be superior to the original?

Comment: Yours will traverse the whole string for each character multiple times.Check @rolfl comment with time complexity of O(mn).